# Combination problem for N items in M identical groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As the title says, I have N different items that will be put in M identical group, N >= M. The size of each group is not defined and the order of groups is not important.

For example, if N = 4 and M = 2, I have the 7 combinations which are:

{1; 2, 3, 4}, {2; 1, 3, 4}, {3; 1, 2, 4}, {4; 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2; 3, 4}, {1, 3; 2, 4} and {1, 4; 2, 3}.

Moreover, combinations {1; 2, 3, 4} and {2, 3, 4} are considered as one combination as above says the order is not important.

If define g(N, M), N >= M, as the total number of combinations, such as g(4, 2) = 7, I have trouble to find out the general form to calculate g(N, M). Hope for the solution and proof.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind have a look at this

Comment: The groups are certainly not identical; I really don't understand what you mean by that. It looks like you are trying to count the [partitions of an $n$ element set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) into $m$ parts; can you confirm that?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I means the groups are the same or unlabeled. Perhaps the term of group has specific meanings and I should not use it here.

Comment: @sasha yes this is what i want, thank you

Comment: Even if the parts (groups, blocks) have no explicit label (and this certainly matters here!) they can still be distinguished by their elements. So I think it is wrong to say they are the same (or identical). I think "unlabelled" is the standard term.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thank you for pointing out the problem and i will be careful about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem [listed in the Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_sx): counting sujective maps from an $N$-element set to a $M$-element set, modulo permutations of the latter set (so that the $M$ non-empty pre-images effectively loose their label; all that remains is a partition of the $N$-element set into $M$ unlabelled subsets). The numbers $g(N,M)$ are called Stirling numbers of the second kind, and often written $\genfrac\{\}0{}NM$.